# App-contextual style function (OpenLayers 4)

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to figure out a way of **having an app-contextual style function** for a Draw interaction (OpenLayers 4).

I have a Draw Interaction constructed with a custom style function (a prototype method of one of my objects), but the problem is that the function will be called with *this* as *Window*, so I can't access to my app context.

As I'm not responsible for that call (called by OpenLayers), I can't specify the *this* I want.

Is there a detail I didn't see in the OpenLayer API, or in javascript (I'm not an expert) that could solve my issue ?

Here is my code :

```
function MyClass(){
    (...)

    // This state should impact the draw interaction style
    this.myState = someValue;

    // My interaction
    this.addInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        (...)
        style: this.styleFunction
    });
}

// My style function which need to access this.myState
MyClass.prototype.styleFunction = function( feature, resolution ) {

    // The following this is Window instead of MyClass.this
    if( this.myState )
        return style1;
    else
        return style2;
}
```

Adding MyClass.this as a Window property is not a solution as I may have multiple instances of MyClass.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution :

The `Function.prototype.bind()` method do the exact job. Use it when giving the style function to the interaction :

```
style: this.styleFunction.bind(this)
```

More informations : [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)